# Move div with onkeydown javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onkeydown

I am trying to make my div move with the arrow keys (37 & 39) and press the spacebar to have a div appear onkeydown and disappear onkeyup.
But the thing is: I want the div to continue to move when I press the spacebar. Right now, the div stops moving when I do so.

I thought putting the keys in an array would work, but it did not, do you have a suggestion to help me? :)

The code has to be in javascript.

```
var keysPressed = new Array();
window.onkeydown = keyDownHandler;
window.onkeyup = keyUpHandler;

function keyDownHandler(e){
    var s="";
    keysPressed[e.which] = true;
    Key = window.event.keyCode;
    s+=Key+" activee:" + keysPressed[e.which];
    updateKeys();
    document.getElementById("moveDiv").innerHTML  = s;
}

function keyUpHandler(e){
     s="";
     keysPressed[e.which] = false;
     Key = window.event.keyCode;
     s+=Key+" activee:" + keysPressed[e.which];
     updateKeys();
     document.getElementById("moveDiv").innerHTML  = s;
}
    var left=0;
    var top = 0;
function updateKeys(){
    if(keysPressed[39]){
        document.getElementById("moveDiv").style.left = left + 10+"px";
        left += 10;
    }
    if(keysPressed[37]){
        document.getElementById("moveDiv").style.left = left -10+"px";
        left-=10;
    }
    if(keysPressed[32]){
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
    }
    if(!keysPressed[32]){
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute;" id="moveDiv"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; 
                left:500px; 
                top:500px; 
                display: none;" id="show">Pressed spacebar</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve? 

## Fiddle

```
function updateKeys() {
    if (keysPressed[0])
        left -= speed;
    if (keysPressed[2])
        left += speed;
    if (keysPressed[1])
        top -= speed;
    if (keysPressed[3])
        top += speed;

    document.getElementById("moveDiv").style.left = left + "px";
    document.getElementById("moveDiv").style.top = top + "px";
    if (spacePressed)
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
    else
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
}

setInterval(updateKeys, 1);
```

[Read about `setInterval` if you are not familiar with it](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

It basically sets a function to run every said milliseconds, in this case every 1 millisecond the function `updateKeys` is executed.

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly! Thanks for the setInterval link, I'll check this up. Have a good day!